# Limit of $S_n=\sqrt[n(n+1)]{\prod _{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

could anyone help me with the limit of the following sequence :
$S_n=\sqrt[n(n+1)]{\prod _{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}}$
Using the GM-AM inequality, we can prove that :
$S_n\le \frac{2}{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\rightarrow2$  and I've been trying to find a sequence $u\le S$ that converges to $2$ (eventhough I have no reason to believe such a sequence exists !) but I can't find any.
Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: It seems from the graph that $\{S_n\}$ is increasing but the limit is less than $\mathrm e^{0.5}≈1.6487$.